# Access codes for controller methods

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I dont want the users to put in method names and their parameters  manually and mess with the method. Im aware i can check for unvalid inputs but what if I call a method that generates an access code and passes that into the main controller with the all the other parameters. If the access code. Then decide that access code, if valid proceed. Is this a little too much and too crazy? What other options would you suggest

```
 Public IActionResult MainMethod(string input, string accesscode)
{ 
//check if access code is correct. I can figure out the decode process and stuff
}

Public IActionResult GenerateCode(string Inputt)
{
// generate a code
Return redirectToAction(“MainMethod” new {input=Inputt , accesscode=accesscode}
});
```

In View when a button is clicked, I call `GenerateCode` first

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass Inputt and generated accesscode from `GenerateCode` to `MainMethod`,why not only pass  input to MainMethod?And then call a method to accesscode,and then check the accesscode in MainMehtod.

```
public IActionResult MainMethod(string input)
        {
            string accesscode = GenerateCode(input);
            //check if access code is correct. I can figure out the decode process and stuff
        }
public string GenerateCode(string Inputt)
        {
            // generate a code
            return accesscode;
        }
```

Comment: accesscode wouldnt actually be in database. it would be a session or a cookie. so if the user manually puts in url and calls the `MainMethod` that shows the view, they dont have `accesscode` is missing and method wont return view

Comment: I mean you can call GenerateCode method in MainMethod,and GenerateCode will generate accesscode and return it to MainMethod.

Comment: Yeah but lets say you as the user call `MainMethod` by typing it in.`MainMethod` would actually perform the action. If you on the other hand click on the button that calls that controller, it generates a one time `accesscode` which means the url wasnt manually typed out. Thats what im trying to achieve here

Comment: But in your  code,you still pass Inputt from view to GenerateCode.GenerateCode and MainMethod are both actions.You pass Inputt to action GenerateCode  or MainMethod ,you both need to get data from view and pass it to action.